# "Host is down" text showing when entering command "reboot"

Tags: reboot

I am trying to enter the reboot command on my Ubuntu but it gives me this text when I enter the command "reboot", "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down"

I am using Microsoft Store version of Ubuntu with a WIndows 10 fully updated. Any fixes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to restart the instance through PowerShell:

1. List your distributions:

   ```
   wsl --list
   ```

   You will see something like:

   ```
   Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
   Ubuntu (Default)
   Fedora
   SUSE
   ```
2. Terminate the appropriate instance:

   ```
   wsl --terminate Ubuntu
   ```
3. Start Ubuntu

If you are running multiple instances, you can shut them all down with:

```
wsl --shutdown
```